# Как сделать такой выбор даты?

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток. Как сделать такой выбор даты? Много перечитал на эту тему, не могу найти, как это сделать. Хелп ми

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий для полноценного ответа. Чтобы реализовать подобный выбор даты, требуется проделать немало работы. Вы можете посмотреть [исходники других диалогов выбора даты](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27) и на их основе сделать свой, либо использовать какую то из готовых библиотек.

Comment: @pavlofff, что значит общий? я спросил как можно сделать, я не просил сделать за меня. За исходники фэкнс

Comment: общий - значит, что сделать такой datepicker - не  десяток строчек кода. Как сделать? Создаете разметку,располагаете элементы, на первый `NumberPicker` вешаете массив `String` с вашими: вчера, сегодня, завтра , на два других - числа из диапазона 0-23 и 0-60.Оформляете все это в диалог. Считываете ввод с пикеров и преобразуете в реальную дату-время.Организуете интерфейс с колбэком для возврата введенной даты "на сторону" ... По каждому из этих пунктов может быть задан конкретный вопрос, но все в одном - общий.

Comment: Если вы хотите получить реальную помощь - напишите , что уже сделали, что не получается,что не понятно .. а не - как такое сделать и картинка

Comment: @pavlofff, мне тут ответили про NumberPicker, мне этого как бы и достаточно. По началу хотел кастомизировать DatePicker, потом узнал про то, что мне нужно.

Answer (score 3):

Как пример можно использовать вот такой код:

```
 private final int IDD_CHECK_CATS = 3;
// часть кода из onCreateDialog()
case IDD_CHECK_CATS:
final boolean[] mCheckedItems = { false, true, false };
final String[] checkCatsName = { "Васька", "Рыжик", "Мурзик" };
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Выберите котов")
        .setCancelable(false)

        .setMultiChoiceItems(checkCatsName, mCheckedItems,
                new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which, boolean isChecked) {
                        mCheckedItems[which] = isChecked;
                    }
                })

        // Добавляем кнопки
        .setPositiveButton("Готово",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int id) {
                        StringBuilder state = new StringBuilder();
                        for (int i = 0; i < checkCatsName.length; i++) {
                            state.append("" + checkCatsName[i]);
                            if (mCheckedItems[i])
                                state.append(" выбран\n");
                            else
                                state.append(" не выбран\n");
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                state.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                })

        .setNegativeButton("Отмена",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                });
return builder.create();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Источник [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/alertdialog.php), очень хорошо расписано как делать. Не описан циферблат, но я думаю найти не составит труда.

Comment: Т.е сделать на обычном AlertDialog? Нельзя решить это через стандартный datepicker?

Comment: @ПавелДурa тут вам datepicker не поможет. Либо искать библиотеку, либо делать свой NumberPicker. Ищите по запросу NumberPicker и как его кастомизировать.

Comment: @ПавелДурa ок, поправлю